# Ajax response processing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use this lines to processing responseText from Ajax call.

```
response=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
    len=response.length;
    console.log(len);
    for(i=0;i<len; i++){
        console.log(i);
        alert(response[i].IPO)
        //COCView.lb01Select.appendChild(new DOMtag('option'{'id':response[i].CO_HDR_ID,'innerHTML':response[i].ONR}));
    }
}
```

After i want to use the inside function(appendChild), I can fetch only the first object of the response array!
Could help me somebody, why stops the cycle?

Comment: what do you mean by inside `function(appendChild)`? where is the rest of your code?

Comment: How does 'response' look like?

Comment: I mean: after activating the COCView.. line, the cycle stops.. actually i just want to fill a <select> with <option>s

Comment: response is an object like: [{"CO_HDR_ID":"1"},{"CO_HDR_ID":"2"}] and it is jsonized

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting all of that inside an anonymous function and see if that helps, such as:

```
JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText, function(response){ 
  len=response.length;
  console.log(len);
  for(i=0;i<len; i++){
    console.log(i);
    alert(response[i].IPO)
    //COCView.lb01Select.appendChild(new DOMtag('option'{'id':response[i].CO_HDR_ID,'innerHTML':response[i].ONR}));
  }
});
```

Also, dump what you are getting for "response" and see if that is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not related to AJAX, issue is the looping process.
Using of for (){} looping process on arrays stops if you have a function within looping. Right looping solution on arrays is:

```
anyfunc=function(x,y,z){..}
array1=[{"id":'one',"IPO":'anyIPOValue'},{"id":'two',"IPO":'anyIPOValue'}];
for(n of array1){
    if (n.id || n.IPO){anyfunc(n.id,n.id,n.IPO);}
    }
```